# How to block external script url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://example.js"></script>
```

I would like this script not to be executed. I can't manually remove it from the page, I can add html and js code. I have other external scripts on the site so I can't block them all.
How can I block/remove this script?

Comment: Can you place a `<script>` tag before the `example.com` script?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I can

Comment: Have a look at [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Comment: Are you using a free host service where the website pushes scripts into your html files, to show their banners?, so you want to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution would probably to go into your server's configuration and setup a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to whitelist only the scripts that you want to permit to run on your page. This will not only solve your problem, it's also a good practice *in general* to prohibit browsers from executing scripts from untrustworthy sources just in case a bad `<script src` accidentally gets included.

Lacking that, it's also possible to remove the `<script>` tag with Javascript, by attaching a MutationObserver right before the bad script runs:

```html
<script>
new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    for (const addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
      // Test if the addedNode is the script tag you want to remove
      // Insert whatever logic is required here
      if (addedNode.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
        addedNode.remove();
        // Disconnect the observer, it's not needed anymore
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }
  
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
</script>

<script>
  alert('evil script to remove');
</script>

<script>
  console.log('a non-evil script');
</script>
```

(but that's an X solution to an X/Y problem, usually)